# Unhandled rejection TypeError: sequalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, node-modules

I am getting this error when i am calling retrieveCart function? What is the error in query of find all. I have a foreign key named productID made by sequelize automatically in my cartProducts table?

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of
>   undefined

```
const Product = db.define('products', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    pic: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Cart = db.define('cartProduct',{
    cid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    qty:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue:1
    }
});

Product.sync({}).then(()=>{
    Cart.belongsTo(Product);
    Cart.sync({});
    Product.destroy({
        where:{}
    });
    Cart.destroy({
        where:{}
    });
    console.log("DataBase Created");
    var i ,len = products.length;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        Product.create({
            id:i+1,
            name: products[i].name,
            price: products[i].price,
            pic: products[i].img
        }).then(()=>{
            console.log("Data Inserted");

        });
    }
});


function retrieveCart() {
    return Cart.findAll({
        include:[{
            modal:Product,
            attributes:['name','price']}]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct `modal:Product` to `model:Product,`